# Redirect HTTPS request

Tags: redirect, https, proxy

I am working on a parental control type project with all traffic going through the control proxy. Certain sites must be redirected to a 'block' type page. This is no problem for HTTP but how do I do this (can I do this) for an HTTPS request such as:

Request to https://dodgy.com, proxy redirects browser to http\https://parentalcontrol.com/blocked

My understanding is that for HTTPS the SSL connection is negotiated first. The proxy would have to intercept this initial negotiation and return some fail status to the browser; but can it also send back a redirect that the browser will be happy with and act upon?

Thanks.